# How to Load Map Image in webview and handle touch area wise android?

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview

I am working on webview.in webview i want to load map image using HTML content and in html content i define cordintes of image area wise. Now i want to take href value onTouch from map tag.so how can i do how can i get href value in webview ontouch from HTML content android. This image  I have to load.  [image]

Below code is my HTML content I define area wise coordinates and give name in href value. How can I get this value?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>map_usa_856</title>
</head>

<body>
<img src="map_usa_320.png" width="320" height="266" style="margin:0 auto; display:block;" usemap="#Map" border="0" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="poly" href="North Carolina" alt="North Carolina" title="North Carolina" coords="266,109,267,107,270,107,270,105,273,102,278,100,277,98,275,98,276,96,278,96,280,93,278,91,277,91,278,90,277,88,245,93,244,97,242,97,239,100,236,102,233,102,232,104,231,104,231,105,237,104,240,102,250,102,250,102,252,104,258,102">
  <area shape="poly" href="North Dakota" alt="North Dakota" title="North Dakota" coords="119,17,152,17,155,38,118,36">
  <area shape="poly" href="Rhode Island" alt="Rhode Island" title="Rhode Island" coords="289,48,291,53,292,52,302,54,302,57,311,57,311,51,302,51,302,53,292,51,291,48">
  <area shape="poly" href="Illinois" alt="Illinois" title="Illinois" coords="208,79,207,80,208,82,207,85,205,87,205,91,203,93,203,93,202,93,200,93,200,95,198,93,199,90,192,87,194,82,191,82,190,82,190,80,185,77,185,75,187,69,187,67,190,67,192,62,189,60,204,59,204,60,206,62">
  <area shape="poly" href="New Mexico" alt="New Mexico" title="New Mexico" coords="117,96,83,93,78,130,83,131,84,127,92,129,92,127,115,129">
  <area shape="poly" href="Georgia" alt="Georgia" title="Georgia" coords="255,123,252,123,252,120,250,119,249,117,247,117,246,114,242,114,241,111,240,109,237,107,236,107,236,105,222,107,227,121,231,125,229,127,229,130,229,132,231,134,247,133,247,134,249,131,252,131,252,128,252,125,254,124">
</map>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution using the `WebClient` class:

```
webUsmap.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
{
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
   {
            Log.e("String HrefValue :-",url);
   }
});
```

Using this, I got the value Of `Href` like: "North Carolina"